# Insert ID field generated from trigger, but not passed along

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL, I have a trigger:

```
BEGIN
   IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM devices WHERE device_id = NEW.device_id)) THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
   ELSE
INSERT INTO objects (object_type) VALUES ('3');
SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   END IF;
END
```

When this trigger gets a new id (from the objects table) it inserts the id into the id column of the devices table.

When I refer to it (for example with `mysql_insert_id();` in PHP), its empty.

How can I return the insert id from the trigger (`LAST_INSERT_ID();`) to the function in PHP as the `mysql_insert_id();` ?

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` should work if `mysql_insert_id();` cannot obtain it, however if the ID you want is from a insertion prior the trigger then I am afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use stored procedures.

Here is a basic example with PDO:

Code to create the **Stored Procedures**:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertUser`(IN `Input_username` INT, OUT `Out_ID` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO users(
        username)
    VALUES (
    Input_username);

    SET Out_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SELECT Out_ID;
END
```

And **PHP code**:

```
  $insert = "CALL InsertUser(:Input_username,
                             @Out_ID)";
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db-name', 'user', 'password');

  $stmt = $bdd->prepare($insert);     
  $stmt->bindParam(':Input_username', rand(), PDO::PARAM_STR); // to create random name

  $stmt->execute();
  $tabResultat = $stmt->fetch();
  $id_user = $tabResultat['Out_ID'];
  var_dump($id_user);
```

I hope I have helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is [by design](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If a stored procedure executes statements that change the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the changed value is seen by statements that follow the procedure call.
>
> For stored functions and triggers that change the value, the value is restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements will not see a changed value.

- Workaround 1: [Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354202/1446005)

Unfortunately this introduces a risk of inconsistencies between your table and `objects`, as insertions could still happen outside of this procedure (this problem *could* be adressed with convoluted access restrictions on the table)

- Workaround 2:

Save the value in a user variable:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
....
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO objects (object_type) VALUES ('3');
    SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET @myLastInsertID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END //

INSERT INTO your_table... -- trigger the above
SELECT @myLastInsertID; -- here is your value
```

- Workaround 3:

Simply get the value from `object` ;)

```
INSERT INTO your_table... -- trigger the above
SELECT MAX(autoinc_column) FROM objects; -- here is your value!
```

Workarounds 2 and 3 should be wrapped in a transaction to ensure no-one interferes with `@myLastInsertID` or `object` during the process.