# calling stored procedure using output parameter which is ref cursor by zend framework 1

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, stored-procedures, zend-db

I have the following oracle procedure:

```
TYPE VarRecCur IS RECORD (
     CustomerId     Customer.CustomerId%TYPE,
     Name           Customer.Name%TYPE
     );

TYPE VarCursor_CUSTOMER IS REF CURSOR RETURN VarRecCur;

PROCEDURE PROC_Customer(pCustomerId IN VARCHAR2,RECOUTPUT IN OUT VARCURSOR_CUSTOMER)
IS
BEGIN
   OPEN RECOUTPUT FOR
   SELECT CustomerId, Name FROM Customer
   WHERE CustomerId =  pCustomerId
END PROC_Customer;
```

Now I tried to get an customer array using zend-db from zend framework 1, but I couldn't, that was my try:

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Statement/Oracle.php';

$db = Zend_Db::factory ( 'pdo_oci', array ('dbname' => DB_SERVER,'username' => 'user','password' => 'pass') );
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Oracle($db, "begin PROC_Customer('1',:cursor); end;");
$cursor = new Zend_Db_Cursor_Oracle($db);
$stmt->bindCursor('cursor', $cursor);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($cursor);
```

I made it works, I had to add more new files to my zend library, my question is there another way to call stored procedure using output parameter which is ref cursor by zend framework 1 library?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354202/3351765) to another question, maybe it will help you.
It was for MySql, so I have not tested but I used pdo like you.